# Devices powered and charged via electricity generated by human body

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, biomedical-engineering, energy-storage, microelectronics

I came across articles like:

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2021/02/210210142049.htm

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27836601

and

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2004801/Weve-got-skin-Battery-free-surveillance-device-implanted-flesh.html

I wonder, based on the current bio-engineering technologies and theory, how much power, bio-electricity or otherwise, can be obtained from the human body (like heat, bloodstream, glucose, etc.) to charge some (bio)battery of certain devices attached to or implanted in the human body (like a detector that collects information and transmits signals to receiver from a certain distance, as in the third article)? Is such technology realistic now or does it have concrete applications?

Comment: Let's hope its not enough to supply power to AI controlled machines after a nuclear holocaust  :-)

Comment: There are papers and several books that mention how much heat a person gives off to a room based on the ambient temperature - used in design of heating and ventilation systems.

Comment: So instead of staying in the realm of Sci-Fi, we can now look forward to people being kidnapped and harnessed so their blood or body energy can be used to drive things. :) The wonders of progress.

Comment: @NMech: Are you implying [*The Matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_(franchise)) is real? ;-)

Comment: @Fred I took the red and blue pill so I am bit confused right now. :-P  (jokes aside the OP is a very interesting question).